# Nested Case Structure in VB.net with more than one variable

Tags: vb.net, nested

I'm working on a project for my Intro to programming class and got stuck on this question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqhFV.png

So far this is my code

```
Private Sub btnShoe_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShoe.Click
    Dim Name, Gender, Foot As String
    Name = InputBox("Enter Your Name", "Name")
    Gender = InputBox("Enter Your Gender (M/F)", "Gender")
    Foot = InputBox("Enter your foot size in inches", "Foot Size")
    'User Input Name, Gender, Foot Size

    Select Case Gender.ToUpper
        Case "M" To "F"
            Select Case Foot
                Case "9.5"
                    MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Mens 7")
                    Case "9.6"
                    MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Mens 7")
                        Case "9.7" To "9.9"
                        MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Mens 8")
                Case "10" To "10.3"
                    MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Mens 9")
                                Case "10.4" To "10.6"
                                MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Mens 10")
                                    Case "10.7" To "10.9"
                                    MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Mens 11")
                                        Case "11" To "11.3"
                                        MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Mens 12")
                                            Case "11.4" To "11.6"
                                            MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Mens 13")
                Case Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Size Unknown")

                    Select Case Gender.ToUpper
                        Case "F"
                            Select Case Foot
                                Case "8.6" To "8.7"
                                    MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Womens 6")
                                Case "8.8" To "9.3"
                                    MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Womens 7")
                                Case "9.4" To "9.5"
                                    MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Womens 8")
                                Case "9.6" To "9.9"
                                    MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Womens 9")
                                Case "10" To "10.2"
                                    MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Womens 10")
                                Case "10.3" To "10.5"
                                    MessageBox.Show("Your Size is a Womens 11")
                                Case Else
                                    MessageBox.Show("Size Unknown")


                            End Select
                    End Select
            End Select
    End Selectenter code here
```

But when I run it, The male sizes work great but if the user inputs female, then there are no errors, but no message box shows.

Comment: Even if genders did come in a vast range of F, G, H, I, J, K, L and M, your range is inverted.  Since you need to look up F in a difference chart than M, there need to be handled separately.  Read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: Also, testing numerical ranges by comparing strings is opening the door for unintended behavior

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two `Select Case Gender.ToUpper`s; and `Case "M" To "F"` should just be `Case "M"` You also need to `End Select` for the inner select. I'm not going to rewrite your code for you, but here's some pseudocode to get you going on the right track:

```
Select Case Gender.ToUpper
    Case "M":
        Select Case Foot
            ....
        End Select
    Case "F":
        Select Case Foot
            ....
        End Select
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you Very Much! It ran perfectly.